# How to retore mysql which is accidentally imported the old mysql dump data

Tags: mysql

I accidentally import the old mysql  dump file in mysql. So I lost latest data. I want to restore mysql data as it was earlier. How to do it. Please guide me

Comment: import the dump from your last backup just like you did with the old dump file. no backup = your data is gone.

Comment: yeah ...i didnt take latest backup..

Comment: you may still be able to restore from bin logs depending on how you setup your mysql server. Someone over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

may be more likely to help you.